# MySQL Tag System (Toxi)

Tags: mysql, count

I have a tagging system consisting of 3 tables:

```
POSTS  - Fields: ID, TITLE
TAGMAP - Fields: POSTID,TAGID
TAGS   - Fields: ID,NAME
```

Currently, I use this query to get the number of posts for each tags:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tagmap WHERE tagmap.tagid=t.id) AS count FROM tags AS t ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

This gives me a list of tags, with the post count for each:

```
ID    NAME       COUNT
----------------------
1     banana     8
2     apple      4
3     pudding    7
4     lemon      3
```

Now, I have a search engine that allows you to click on a tag, and get the posts that are related to that tag. If I click "apple" by example, I get the matching posts. But some of these posts also have the "banana" and "pudding" tags. I need to know the count of each, to generate a new menu with the updated post count.

So if I click apple, there will be 4 posts. Of these 4 posts, 2 has the "pudding" tag, and 3 has the "lemon" tag. I would need an output like that:

```
ID    NAME       COUNT
----------------------
1     banana     0
2     apple      4
3     pudding    2
4     lemon      3
```

If we continue that way, if I click "lemon" (so we are now loading posts related to "apple" AND "lemon"), and there's 1 of the post that have the "lemon" tag also have the "pudding" tag, I would need an output like that:

```
ID    NAME       COUNT
----------------------
1     banana     0
2     apple      4
3     pudding    1
4     lemon      3
```

I am not sure if it's clear enough - if you need any more informations please tell me.

Comment: Maybe that can help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f1d0d/1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    matchTags.id, matchTags.name, COUNT(matchTagMap.tagid) AS count
FROM 
    (SELECT postid 
    FROM 
        tags AS searchTags
        JOIN tagmap AS searchTagMap
            ON searchTags.id = searchTagMap.tagid
        WHERE searchTags.name IN ('apple', 'pudding')
        GROUP BY searchTagMap.postid
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    ) dt

    CROSS JOIN tags AS matchTags
    LEFT JOIN tagmap AS matchTagMap
        ON dt.postid = matchTagMap.postid AND matchTagMap.tagid = matchTags.id
GROUP BY matchTags.id;
```

Adjust the list of tag names and the HAVING COUNT(*) line to match.